# Inequation + Lambert-W function

Tags: calculus, inequality, lambda-calculus

I don't know how to put : 
$9x\cdot 10^x-8\cdot 10^x > 10^7$ in the form : 
$b\cdot e^b > a$ so that i can use the Lambert-W function to solve this inequality
Any ideas ?

Comment: You forgot something in your second inequation, as the latter is solved by logarithms alone.

Comment: Yes my bad. I edited it.

Answer (score 3):

$$(9x-8)10^x>10^7$$

Shift by $8/9$

$$9y\,10^y10^{8/9}>10^7$$

Scale by $\ln10$,

$$\frac{9z}{\log10}e^z10^{8/9}>10^7$$

Divide

$$ze^z>\frac{\log10}{9}10^{7-8/9}$$

Comment: Thank you, but with your solution I don't find $z > 5.39...$

Comment: @Thinking: it's not "my solution", it's the truth. Every step is rigorous. It yields $5.392223\cdots$.